# How is TCF calculated for a Current Transformer?

Tags: transformer, standard

I'm trying to understand the IEEE C57.13 standards for current transformer metering accuracy, and I don't understand how the Transformer Correction Factor (TCF) is defined for current transformers. Section 5.1 says:

> Accuracy classes for revenue metering are based on the requirement that the transformer correction factor (TCF) of the voltage transformer or of the current transformer shall be within the specified limits when the power factor (lagging) of the metered load has any value from 0.6 to 1.0 [...]

Then in section 5.2:

> It can be shown that a TCF at 0.6 power factor (lagging) of the metered load is as follows*: [...]

> For current transformers

> TCF = RCF - B/2600

> Where RCF is the ratio correction factor derived from 1 - (±Ratio Error/100)

> B is the phase angle in minutes

1. Is this equation valid for all lagging power factors between 0.6 and 1.0?
2. Why is the 2600 in the TCF equation? How is it derived, or is it just a magic number?

For this question, I'm primarily interested in the TCF calculation for CTs (which is why I've omitted calculations for the VT TCF).

**Edit:** I missed the footnote at the beginning of section 5.2:

> This is true of errors within the range of the standard metering accuracy classes.

So question 1 has an answer, but I'm still not clear on question 2.

Comment: Your 2nd quotation doesn't provide enough information as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yeah, there's not much more material in the Standard. Section 5.3 is basically a table with the different metering accuracy classes' requirements, and Section 5.4 is mostly graphs showing acceptable Ratio Correction Factor vs phase angle.

Comment: 2600 translates to 43.333 degrees and, that's a cos(phi) of 0.727, if that's of any use to you. It's probably a magic number.